# SOAP или RESTAPI для написания своего API на c#?

Tags: c#, soap, rest

Существует задача: написать свой API для приложения на C#, вопрос очень простой как это лучше реализовать, какие технологии использовать?
В процессе поисков наткнулся на gSOAP вот только все очень заморочено, есть ли какие либо альтернативы? 
Буду рад любым советам и ссылкам на источники.
Спасибо, всем откликнувшимся!!!

Comment: сейчас REST API принято писать, SOAP уже трудно встретить. На c# лучше использовать WebApi https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh833994(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: А сервер на чем? Если тоже на C# и под винду, то берите WCF и не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: Дело в том что сервер на C++, а клиент на С#. Очень важно чтобы данные передавались в формате JSON. Ничего годного кроме gSOAP не нашел. Как я понял на сервере gSOAP должен генерировать file.h который мне нужно как то распарсить и передать на клиент, как это сделать совершенно не понятно, уже несколько дней читаю документацию и не понимаю, если у кого то был опыт работы с gSOAP объясните дураку, буду рад любым советам. Спасибо!!!